# Does Android runtime reload class at warm startup?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am wondering whether static initialize block will be called at warm start for android. What I know is that static init block will be called only once when class load, but does android runtime do class load only at once when cold start or it needs to load it again at warm start?

Does it depend on whether application still runs or kicked out of memory?

Comment: What do you consider a "warm startup" and a "cold startup" to be?

Comment: Sorry it should be warm start and cold start. Just like the android doc characterized: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time

Answer (score 0):

Google's documentation there sucks, IMHO. In particular, their "warm start" definition is awful.

With respect to static initializers, they will run when the class is loaded for the first time in the process.

So, using Google's terms:

- A cold start, by definition, means that a fresh process was created for your app, so static initializers will be executed as needed, as you reference their classes
- A hot start, by definition, means that your process already existed, and so any static initializers that had run previously do not get run again
- Google's first warm start scenario ("The user backs out of your app, but then re-launches it") is a hot start, at least in terms of static initializers
- Google's second warm start scenario ("The system evicts your app from memory, and then the user re-launches it") is a cold start, at least in terms of static initializers

Comment: "Google's documentation there sucks" - Google try to make sure its documentation never contradicts itself .... solution ... ambiguity .. either that or they think "Leave the crowd always wanting more ..."